# How to redirect IP to https://domain in .htaccess

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.3

My websites open with IP, But i need redirect IP to domain.

I create project with Laravel framework.

My server is **Ubuntu 16.04**

My .htaccess is: // This file is root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
  RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^10\.10\.10\.10
  RewriteRule (.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But this code not work with me.

Thank you

Comment: Hi @anubhava , Now, I can open website with IP, This IP not redirect to https://domain.

Comment: Check your access log and see what is exact request that is coming

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write in the end of `http.conf file`.
ip redirection to domain name under the `<Virtualhost *:80>`

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 

ServerName < Server_hostname >    
ServerAlias *    
Redirect / https://< Server_hostname >/    

</VirtualHost>    

##https://ip redirection to domain name under the <Virtualhost *:443>

<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName < Server_hostname >    
ServerAlias *    
Redirect / https://< Server_hostname >/    

</VirtualHost>
```